# Encountering out of memory error while reversing a short doubly linked list in java

Tags: java, reverse, tostring, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to reverse a doubly-linked list and print it by overriding the toString method. I used a template for the implementation of a doubly-linked list in java, and only added one method: reverse().

I've spent quite some time debugging, and was able to print out the entire reversed list properly. However, when the testReverse() function runs and calls the overridden toString() method on the new reversed list, I get a `java.lang.outofmemoryerror java heap space` error thrown at me. I've included the entire implementation of the doubly-linked list I used below, but I'm almost certain the issue concerns my algorithm.

Any and all insight or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
public class LinkedList<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    private int size;
    private Node<T> beginMarker;
    private Node<T> endMarker;

    private class Node<NodeT> {
        public Node(NodeT d, Node<NodeT> p, Node<NodeT> n) {
            data = d;
            prev = p;
            next = n;
        }

        public NodeT data;
        public Node<NodeT> prev;
        public Node<NodeT> next;
    }

    public LinkedList() {
        doClear();
    }

    public void doClear() {
        beginMarker = new Node<>(null, null, null);
        endMarker = new Node<>(null, beginMarker, null);
        beginMarker.next = endMarker;
        size = 0;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    private Node<T> getNode(int idx, int lower, int upper) {
        Node<T> p;

        if (idx < lower || idx > upper)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("getNode index: " + idx + "; size: "+ size());

        if (idx < size() / 2) { // Search through list from the beginning
            p = beginMarker.next;
            for (int i = 0; i < idx; i++)
                p = p.next;
        } else { // serch through the list from the end
            p = endMarker;
            for (int i = size(); i > idx; i--)
                p = p.prev;
        }
        return p;
    }

    private Node<T> getNode(int idx) {
        return getNode(idx, 0, size() - 1);
    }

    public T get(int idx) {
        return getNode(idx).data;
    }

    public T set(int idx, T newVal) {
        Node<T> p = getNode(idx);
        T oldVal = p.data;

        p.data = newVal;
        return oldVal;
    }

    private void addBefore(Node<T> p, T x) {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<>(x, p.prev, p);
        newNode.prev.next = newNode;
        p.prev = newNode;
        size++;
    }

    public void add(int idx, T x) {
        addBefore(getNode(idx, 0, size()), x);
    }

    public void add(T x) {
        add(size(), x);
    }

    private T remove(Node<T> p) {
        p.next.prev = p.prev;
        p.prev.next = p.next;
        size--;
        return p.data;
    }

    public T remove(int idx) {
        return remove(getNode(idx));
    }
  
    public void reverse() {

        Node current = beginMarker.next;
        Node temp = null;

        while (current != endMarker) {
            temp = current.next; // store reference to next node
            current.next = current.prev; // next points to previous node
            current.prev = temp; // prev points to next node
            current = temp; // current references temp (next node).
        }

        // changing references of beginning and end nodes
        temp = beginMarker.next;
        beginMarker.next = endMarker.prev;
        endMarker.prev = temp;

        /* TESTING THE PROGRAM, THIS PRINTS THE REVERSED LIST 'PROPERLY' BUT THE TESTER METHOD DOESN'T WORK */
        current = beginMarker;
        for (int i = 0; i <= size() + 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(current.data);
            current = current.next;

            /* END TEST */
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[ ");
        for (T x : this) {
            sb.append(x + " ");
        }
        sb.append("]");
        return new String(sb);
    }

    public java.util.Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new LinkedListIterator();
    }

    private class LinkedListIterator implements java.util.Iterator<T> {
        private Node<T> current = beginMarker.next;
        private boolean okToRemove = false;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current != endMarker;
        }

        public T next() {
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();

            T nextItem = current.data;
            current = current.next;
            okToRemove = true;
            return nextItem;
        }

        public void remove() {
            if (!okToRemove)
                throw new IllegalStateException();

            LinkedList.this.remove(current.prev);
            okToRemove = false;
        }
    }

  public static void testReverse(){
    
    LinkedList<Integer> lst = new LinkedList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            lst.add(i);
        for (int i = 20; i < 30; i++)
            lst.add(0, i);
    
    System.out.println("Testing reverse:");
    System.out.println("Original list:");
    // Should print [ 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ] 
        System.out.println(lst);
    lst.reverse();
    System.out.println("After reversal:");
    // Should print [ 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 ] 
        System.out.println(lst);
    
  }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testReverse();
    }
}
```

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger. Presumably you are not correctly assigning endMarker somewhere. Use a smaller list to make debugging simpler.

Comment: And see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: It's most likely the `while` loop that never ends. Can you check that?

Comment: @Charles The entire program runs, including the print statements below the while loop, so I don't think this is the issue. Please let me know if I'm missing something, though!

Comment: Sooo the iterator is broken? Debug the iterator why its not stopping. `hasNext()` probably always returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void reverse() {

        Node current = beginMarker.next;
        Node temp = null;

        while (current != endMarker) {
            temp = current.next; // store reference to next node
            if (current == beginMarker.next) {
                current.next = endMarker;
            } else {
                current.next = current.prev; // next points to previous node
            }
            current.prev = temp; // prev points to next node
            current = temp; // current references temp (next node).
        }

        // changing references of beginning and end nodes
        temp = beginMarker.next;
        beginMarker.next = endMarker.prev;
        endMarker.prev = temp;

        /* TESTING THE PROGRAM, THIS PRINTS THE REVERSED LIST 'PROPERLY' BUT THE TESTER METHOD DOESN'T WORK */
        current = beginMarker;
        for (int i = 0; i <= size() + 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(current.data);
            current = current.next;

            /* END TEST */
        }
    }
```

Comment: This worked, but I'm struggling to understand what the issue here was. If you wouldn't mind, could you help me understand my initial mistake? Thanks very much.

Comment: While debugging your program, it takes up 6 GB of memory. I don't have a memory analysis tool to see what's going on in memory. The first element should be the last element after flipping. On the first loop, "current.next = current.prev; 'causes the next element of the first element to point to beginMarker, which is clearly wrong.